# Hiding duplicate Record from datalist / grid view

Tags: asp.net, sql

i have a data list in which i am displaying record from two different tables like this

```
string outBox = "Select DISTINCT ToUserID from OutboxMessages WHERE FromUserID = '" + Session["UserId"].ToString() + " ' ";

String inBox = "Select DISTINCT FromUserID from InboxMessages WHERE ToUserID = '" + Session["UserId"].ToString() + " ' ";

con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=EventOrganizer;Integrated Security=True");
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(outBox, con);
        da.Fill(ds1, "Record");
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(inBox, con);
        da.Fill(ds2, "Record");
        ds1.Merge(ds2);
        GridView2.DataSource = ds1;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        DataList1.DataSource = ds1;
        DataList1.DataBind();
output is:
FromUserID ToUserID
3
7
            2
            7
```

see 7 is appearing twice i want it to appear only once ..any ideas??

Comment: Appear only once means? How do you want to display it in datalist?

Comment: for example if userid  7 appears either in fromuserid or touserId i  want to hide it after first time.every id should appear only once either in fromuserid column or touserid column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new table with the filtered data from Original table and bind that new table to datalist. A sample below

Create a new table first

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("FromUserID", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("ToUserID", typeof(string));

if(ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
  foreach(DataRow rw in ds1.Tables[0].Rows)
  {
     if(rw["FromUserID"] != rw["ToUserID"])
      {
        dt.Rows.Add(rw["FromUserID"].ToString(), rw["ToUserID"].ToString());
      }
      else
       {
           dt.Rows.Add(rw["FromUserID"].ToString(), "");
       }
  }
}
```

Bind this newly created table to datalist

```
    DataList1.DataSource = dt;
    DataList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: this is not working i found the solution , applied UNION on both of these query and got my results , anyways thanks :)

Comment: @ShoaibIsmail, Good to know that you have found solution but not sure how union will get you result the way you are trying to display. Moreover, I am pretty sure that the code I have posted will work fine and no idea why it didn't worked for you.